# Paperclip add a image in the code

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, paperclip

I wish to use the paperclip gem to add an image that I am retrieving from an API for my user model using code.

How can I attach an image manually using code, rather than passing in parameters from a submitted form ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your model object is `@bar`, image field is called `:logo` and you want to attach `foo.jpg`...

`@bar[:logo] = File.open('foo.jpg')` should work. Or am I misunderstanding the question?

You'd need to initialize your paperclip attachments in a similar way if you were populating from seed data, for example.

Comment: Thats what I was after.  Thanks heaps.